# Showing video & Images in grid view In android

Tags: android, gridview, streaming, android-image, android-video-player

I am developing an application which has to show images& video in an grid view & all this data comes from server as a json.
    I got json parsing but very much confused how to show both images & video in single grid view. At the same time if user select any cell of that grid view it must display that contain.

```
Please give some links and demos for such an application. 

 I think it must work like in build gallery view in android phone.
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it helps, I found this sample from a question here @ stackoverflow some months ago

**http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2009/09/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html**

Comment: Jorgesys Thanks for quick reply.
         But main problem is All images & video comes from server I have only links to show.